# adding "static" to many entries in a DJango html file

Tags: django, awk, sed, tags

I need to add the "static" feature to a number of files in my DJango project as mentioned here: [howto: static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

It seems to work. But, the instruction says that one needs to make this change

```
OLD:
 <img src="my_app/example.jpg" alt="My image"/>

NEW:
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}" alt="My image"/>
```

to every line that needs it.

I have several hundred lines of already-existing code that is in the old format. How can one change so many lines so at one time so that they will be in the correct format? In "vi", one can use something like:

**:1,$ s/static/{% static '/**

but that would only take care of the left-hand-side. The right-hand-side would still need: **' %"}** . The files being used are sometimes .css, .jpg, .png, and others.

TIA

Here is a sample:

```
<link href="/static/wforms/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/static/wforms/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/static/wforms/assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/static/wforms/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jqvmap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

[... snip ...]

<div class="mt-avatar">
<img src="/static/wforms/assets/pages/media/users/avatar80_1.jpg" />
</div>

[... snip ...]
```

## Update

@SLePort - thanks for the answer. For my situation, just made a few changes:

The "sed" script creates the result so that - on the right-hand-side - one gets

**%}** and not **%} "** (with the extra quote on the end) - see example below

```
<link href="{% static "wforms/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %} rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{% static "wforms/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" %} rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So, I just ran

```
:1,$ s/%}/\'%}/g
```

in the vi editor and all was fine.

Thanks again!

Comment: if you use emacs for example, you can use something called multiple cursors. Sublime, atom and many editors has this tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, you can use [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) and the `-i` flag to edit you file in place:

```
sed -i 's|="/static/\([^"]*\)"|="{% static "\1" %}|' file
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me is to apply a regex using some text editor. Use replace:

```
my_app
```

for:

```
{% static 'my_app
```

and for the final bit:

```
jpg
```

for:

```
jpg' %}
```

If you use linux, gedit or xed. In windows notepad++ is a good choice for these things.(Or your code editor sure has the function replace)

**Edit**

[Komodo edit](https://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide/downloads/edit) lets you replace in different files at the same time.

Hope it helped.

**Edit 2**

Here are the regexp that seem to work:

`(href="|src=")`

replace with

`\1\2{%` (adjust this as you need)

The last part:

`(jpg|\.css)`

replace with

`\1\2' %}`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have thought of using "vi", where one could do what you are saying. The problem is that it is not always a .jpg file. Sometimes it is "href=", sometimes it is "src=", etc. I will update the original text with an example. I was now thinking of trying to use something like 'sed' or 'awk'

Comment: Now I changed the answer with a tested code I used [notepadqq](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/s/). Don't forget to mark the answer as useful if it solved your problem.

Comment: thanks for the input. Take a look at SLePort's answer above. He does all with one "sed" command.

Comment: @CaseyHarrils Hehe yes, commands are awesome! But you have to learn how they work and learn more complex regex patterns, wich is not bad, but could be more prone to errors. +1 to SlePort